# Matching Array with Column of a Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord

I have an array of certain dates called `array_of_dates`.

And I have a table called `my_table` with columns 'date' and 'count'.

Is there a way I can write an active records query to match the 'date' column in `my_table` with `array_of_dates` and return hashes ? All **keys** being the dates from `array_of_dates`, and all the **values** being the 'count' from `my_table`; returning zero as the **value** if a date present in `array_of_dates` doesn't exist in column 'date' of `my_table`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Model.select("date, count").
  where(:date => array_of_dates).
    reduce(Hash.new(0)){ |h, r| h[r.date] = r.count;h}
```

Answer (score 1):

The SQL could look like this:

```
SELECT date_col AS key, count(t.date_col) AS value
FROM  (
   SELECT unnest('{2012-07-08, 2012-07-09, 2012-07-10}'::date[]) AS date_col
   ) x
LEFT   JOIN tbl t USING (date_col)
GROUP  BY date_col;
```

Key elements are the subquery with [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) and the `LEFT JOIN` instead of a plain join.

`values` will be `0` if no match is found for a date because `count(t.date_col)` does not count `NULL` values.